# Blocking methods on a variable being set

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Obj-C class where I have the following :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *header;

- (NSString *)doMethodA;
- (NSString *)doMethodB;
- (NSString *)doMethodC;
```

The problem I have is I don't know which of these methods are called by the consuming code, but what I need to do is to make sure that none of the doMethod* calls return till header is set. of course the naive way of :

```
- (NSString *)doMethodA {
   while(header == nil) {
   }

   return @"methodA"
}
```

I am looking for more elegant solution. One thing I was toying was something like this :

in init method

```
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    - (void)setHeader:(NSString *)header {
       _header = header;
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }
```

and in the method :

```
    - (NSString *)doMethodA {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        return @"methodA"
    }
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Blocking is rarely the answer, especially if the underlying tasks are asynchronous (e.g. network related). If you block the main thread your app will become unresponsive and there is a chance that the code that needs to set the header will be blocked. It sounds like you need a queue of work that can hold requests until the header is set or perhaps some other approach involving retry. Provide more information in your *actual problem*.

Comment: all the doMethod* are network requests. The header is set as a result of a network request. I do not know which one gets called first, so have to wait.

Comment: That's what I suspected and my answer stands; don't block. If you haven't got the token you need for the header, fail the request and retry later. Check the token is available before even trying the request. Use an operation queue and put the token request operation in the queue first....